# Need help converting string or int to float

Tags: string, floating-point, type-conversion, int

So I have been stuck on this one for a while and could use some help. I have been trying to fix this code and I keep getting an error about invalid syntax. So here is the code I need help with need to convert from str or int to float.

```
# Input from the command line
import sys
   A = sys.argv[1]
   B = sys.argv[2]
   C = sys.argv[3]

# Your code goes here
   num = A * (B + C / 3)


# Outputs
   print (float(num))
```

Answer (score 0):

By default,python gets inputs from command line as str.So,you must convert them to floats before applying any operation

```
import sys
A=float(sys.argv[1])
B=float(sys.argv[2])
C=float(sys.argv[3])
.....
```